# Bug overwriting resized images in Cloud Storage from Cloud Functions

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

**Current Situation**

I'm storing profile-pictures in my cloud storage. Everytime one gets added/updated I'd like to produce a resized thumb of it.
So in my cloud functions I added this trigger:

```
import { Storage } from '@google-cloud/storage';
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as fs from 'fs-extra';
import { tmpdir } from 'os';
import { dirname, join } from 'path';
import * as sharp from 'sharp';


const gcs = new Storage();

//Thumb will not override previous thumb.

export const generateThumbs = functions.region('europe-west1')
  .storage
  .object()
  .onFinalize(async object => {
    const bucket = gcs.bucket(object.bucket);


    const filePath = object.name;
    if (filePath) {
      const fileName = filePath.split('/').pop();
      if (fileName) {
        const bucketDir = dirname(filePath);

        const workingDir = join(tmpdir(), 'thumbs', Date.now().toString());
        const tmpFilePath = join(workingDir, fileName);

        if (fileName.includes('thumb@') || (object.contentType && !object.contentType.includes('image'))) {
          console.log('exiting function: ' + fileName);
          return false;
        }
        await fs.ensureDir(workingDir);

        await bucket.file(filePath).download({
          destination: tmpFilePath
        });

        const sizes = [256];

        const uploadPromises = sizes.map(async size => {
          const thumbName = `thumb@${size}_${fileName}`;
          const thumbPath = join(workingDir, thumbName);


          await sharp(tmpFilePath)
            .resize(size, size)
            .toFile(thumbPath);

          return bucket.upload(thumbPath, {
            destination: join(bucketDir, thumbName)
          });
        });


        await Promise.all(uploadPromises);

        return fs.remove(workingDir).then(() => {
          return fs.remove(bucketDir);
        })
      }
    }
    return null;
  });
```

Each user only has 1 profile picture and I don't need to keep the previous profile pictures, so for example, the user id = 25, I upload his image with filename '25.jpeg', the thumb-image 'thumb_256_25.jpeg' gets created correctly.

**Problem**

Now the user changes image, I overwrite the previous '25.jpeg' with a new image (this works as expected), and my cloud function trigger runs. It does upload a new thumb-image on 'thumb_256_25.jpeg'. Very few times the newly uploaded thumb is an actual thumb image of the newly uploaded 25.jpeg image. More often it's either sill the previous one which got re-uploaded, or it's an even older one.

Comment: Do you have [object versioning](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-versioning) enabled on your bucket?

Comment: No. I think i'll try to change the last line, the return fs.remove to await and then return null, maybe it's because the workingdir is still existant when I change the picture and it uploads the previous image from that dir. Or is the return the same as an await? I know this sounds weird, but it's the only thing i can think of. If this problem persists i'll try to delete the previous thumb file with the onDelete trigger and see if it works after that.

Answer (score 0):

Debugging is really hard, but I found that the only viable, working solution was to give the workingDir a unique Folder-name like this:

`const workingDir = join(tmpdir(), 'thumbs', Date.now().toString());`

I've tried several things with fs.remove and fs.unlink, but none of these worked. For me the problem is that the workingDir and therefore the thumbPath and even the tmpFilePath file isn't correctly removed after the function runs. Therefore, on the next run, either sharp is resizing an old image present in tmpFilePath or it's resizing the new downloaded one, but uploading an old one. Though it's weird 'cause I remove that folder at the end of the function.

If anyone has an explanation or another solution, be so kind to share it.